# Сверстать элемент списка

Tags: xml, android, вёрстка

Добрый день.
Возникла следующая проблема: необходимо сверстать элемент списка, так, как показано на картинке.

[image: Imgur]

Собственно проблема в том, что TextView выталкивает второй layout за экран. 
Фактически, мне необходимо, что бы второй layout был вплотную, справа от первого.
P.S. TextView динамически меняет свою ширину (тк текст может быть произвольной длины)

Answer (score 1):

"второй layout" привяжите к родительскому слою `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Comment: Дополню коммент @monomi, делать это все надо в RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю что делать это в RelativeLayout - издевательство и не нужно. Правильный выбор, как мне кажется LinearLayout с параметром weightSum="100" и нужными вам параметрами layout_weight у textView и второго layout. При этом подходе текст произвольной длинны не будет разрывать разметку, а будет красиво переноситься в отведенном ему контейнере, более того относительная верстка будет одинаково выглядеть на разных размерах экрана.